# Populating a list using a service fails in the initial function call but works in the second invoke of the function

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a very weird behaviour which I can't understand.
I have an SQLite Scrum operation using Angular (Ionic Storage). There is an SQLite query in
a Database Service which is like this :

```
  loadLists()
  {
      this.database.executeSql('SELECT * from lists', []).then(data =>
      {
          const shoppingListCollection: Shopping_List[] = [];
          if (!data.empty)
          {
              for (let i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++)
              {
                  shoppingListCollection.push(
                      {
                          id: data.rows.item(i).list_id,
                          name: data.rows.item(i).list_name,
                          created: data.rows.item(i).time_created,
                          due: data.rows.item(i).time_due,
                          type: data.rows.item(i).type_id,
                          list_size: 0
                      });
              }
          }
          this.shoppingLists = shoppingListCollection;
          for (const item of this.shoppingLists)
          {
              console.log( ' ---- item : ' + item.name);
          }
      }).catch(e => {
          console.log('***** Debug - Error : ');
          console.error(e);
      });
      return this.shoppingLists;
  }
}
```

I am using this service by multiple components (or pages). Those components are using the Database Service to be created with their constructors

```
constructor(private db: DatabaseService) {}
```

In one of these components I am trying to call the DatabaseService function and return a list of things like this :

```
  loadShoppingLists()
  {
    let shoppingList: Shopping_List[] = [];
    shoppingList = this.db.loadLists();
    for (const item of shoppingList)
    {
      console.log( ' ++++ item : ' + item.name);
      this.shoppingListCollection.push(item);
    }
  }
```

When I say "things" I mean this :

```
export interface Shopping_List
{
    id: number;
    name: string;
    created: string;
    due: string;
    type: number;
    list_size: number;
}
```

THE PROBLEM : The problem is that the first time I invoke loadShoppingLists() the list that returns in empty, although the debug console outs saw that my SQLite code populated the list inside the Service. The second time I invoke loadShoppingLists(), it populates the list inside the component as well.

Any thoughts about that, I would appreciate any remarks. Thank you.

*** PS ***
Here is the whole repository in case someone has more than 3 minutes and wishes to check the whole code : https://github.com/FotisUHO/shopping-list/tree/master.

Answer (score 1):

you have a race condition in your `loadShoppingLists()` function as `shoppingList = this.db.loadLists()` is not a synchronous call. You have to modify your code to wait for that promise to resolve before proceeding to this next block of code:

```
   for (const item of shoppingList)
    {
      console.log( ' ++++ item : ' + item.name);
      this.shoppingListCollection.push(item);
    }
```

Comment: I changed loadList function to be an async function. I updated to :this.db.loadLists().then( data => {
      shoppingList = data;} but I have the same problems.

Comment: I think you need to research more about promises so you'll know how to handle it properly.

Comment: Indeed. I am a Java - C/C++ software engineer and my js experience is poor. I fixed this by turning the object into a BehaviouralSubject and return an Observable. I render in html file using async directive.

Comment: Np, anytime :D. It was just about ensuring the data exists before proceeding to the next call. make it like synchronous.

Answer (score 1):

I have few suggestion. Try your code again, after adding return statement like this.

```
      this.shoppingLists = shoppingListCollection;
      for (const item of this.shoppingLists)
      {
          console.log( ' ---- item : ' + item.name);
      }
      return this.shoppingLists;
```

I think problem view is render before coming data from sqlite. So if this my suggestion not work, then try, adding setTimeout() function with this.

```
  loadShoppingLists()
  {
    let shoppingList: Shopping_List[] = [];
    shoppingList = this.db.loadLists();

    setTimeout(() => {

      for (const item of shoppingList)
      {
        console.log( ' ++++ item : ' + item.name);
        this.shoppingListCollection.push(item);
      }
  
    },500);
  }
```

Comment: If you notice my code, I treat executeSql as a promise and I fetch the data inside a then block.